# Rails : Simple search form, with keywords jambled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've made a simple search for my rails app. But I want to make it works, even with keywords jambled.
If I have a tweet with "hello world" written, I can sort it by typing "hello world" but it doesn't work if I type "world hello". How can I fix it ? Here is my code :

tweet_controller.rb

```
def index
 @tweets = Tweet.all
  if params[:search]
    @tweets = Tweet.search(params[:search])
  else
    @tweets = Tweet.all
  end
end
```

tweet.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  where("status LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

and the view

```
<%= form_tag(tweets_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Tweets" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

tweet.rb

```
def self.search(search)   
 search_string = search.split(" ").first ##split and search by first keyword
 where("status LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

For `full-text search`, you can use any search engine like [solar](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot)